# ¿Como realizar una unión en MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Tengo lo siguiente en MySQL:

```
SELECT id, nombre, tipo, activo FROM registros
```

El detalle, es que la última columna "Activo" lo estoy manejando mediante 0 = Inactivo, 1 = Activo (Por su index en una jcombobox).

Así que al traer la consulta y llenarlo en la jtable, me trae 1 ó 0.

```
id  -  nombre  -  tipo  -  activo
1     Fulanito    Admin       1
```

Deseo que me traiga **1 sola consulta**, y en la columna de Activo salga **Si o No**, de ser posible, mediante una unión de consultas.
Pude realizar la consulta siguiente:

```
SELECT IF(registros.id = 1, 'SI','NO') AS activo FROM registros
```

Y me reemplaza el 1 por el Si, pero deseo que salga todo en una sola consulta, mostrando lo siguiente en la tabla:

```
id  -  nombre  -  tipo  -  activo
1     Fulanito    Admin      SI
```

No puedo cambiar el campo de Activo en la base de datos, ya que no funcionaria mi jcombobox, e intenté con el join, pero no he logrado que funcione, ya que son dos consultas diferentes.

De antemano, muchas gracias.

Comment: Pero porqué necesitas que en la consulta venga SI o NO?

Comment: Si, exacto, que me salga una consulta completa y que venga SI o NO, en vez de 1 ó 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La consulta que utilizas es correcta, solo te falta agregar las columnas adicionales en el `SELECT`:

```
SELECT id, nombre, tipo, IF(activo = 1, 'SI','NO') AS 'activo' FROM registros;
```

Comment: XD. muchisimas gracias, y yo partiendome la cabeza con los joins, en vez de hacerlo más sencillo. Te mando un mega abrazo.